# Select random values without NaNs in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which is filled with numbers and Nans. And now i want to select for each column a random values only for the numbers!

DataFrame:

([1,2,NaN]

[NaN,8,9]

[1,2,3])

(sorry im new here i dont know how to run code)
`df_ran = df.apply(lambda row : np.random.choice(row.tolist()), axis=0)`
with this line i get random values for each column but with the NaNs

Comment: Basically im looking for some "random(choose_type=int)" function

Comment: Then Delete `nan` from dataframe first. it would work `df_ran = df.dropna().apply(lambda row : np.random.choice(row.tolist()), axis=0)` And check [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) this also